# JavaScript. Вычисление возраста по дате рождения

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Друзья, здравствуйте.

От API партнёров приходит дата рождения пользователя в формате DD.MM.YYYY или DD.MM (если год рождения скрыт).
На основе этих данных нужно определить возраст человека.

Помогите с функцией. Вероятно подошло бы что-то вроде этого, но new Date() не воспринимает дату в формате DD.MM.YYYY

```
function get_current_age(date) {
  return ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(date)) / (24 * 3600 * 365.25 * 1000)) | 0;
}
```

Comment: есть уже готовые библиотеки, которые реализовали это типа moment, или обязательно нужно что то свое?

Comment: библиотеки не желательно использовать

Comment: Date.TryParse() пробовали? [ссылка тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: В принципи можно просто добавить в начало приведённой функции проверку:  var d = date.split('.'); if ( d[2] != "undefined" ) date = d[2]+'.'+d[1]+'.'+d[0] else return false; Но какой-то говнокод получается.

Comment: "или DD.MM (если год рождения скрыт) - определить возраст" - я родился 1-го января - определите мой возраст.

Comment: @Igor, 2016 или 46 :-)

Answer (score 4):

Долго думал как проще реализовать. 
Пришёл к такой схеме: определяем текущую дату, определяем дату рождения, определяем день рождения в текущем году. Вычитаем из текущего года год рождения. Узнаём был ли уже ДР или нет в этом году. Если ещё нет, то вычитаем один год из полученного результата.

```js
var now = new Date(); //Текущя дата
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()); //Текущя дата без времени
var dob = new Date(1990, 9, 31); //Дата рождения
var dobnow = new Date(today.getFullYear(), dob.getMonth(), dob.getDate()); //ДР в текущем году
var age; //Возраст

//Возраст = текущий год - год рождения
age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
//Если ДР в этом году ещё предстоит, то вычитаем из age один год
if (today < dobnow) {
  age = age-1;
}

document.write (`Возраст: ${age}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_current_age(date) {
    var d = date.split('.');
    if( typeof d[2] !== "undefined" ) {
        date = d[2]+'.'+d[1]+'.'+d[0];
        return ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(date)) / (24 * 3600 * 365.25 * 1000)) | 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам сегодня икал, увело на другой ресурс
Найденный метод дописал, так как, если меньше года, то хоть месяцы отдает

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    let today = new Date();
    let birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    let age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

    let m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    let d = today.getDay() - birthDate.getDay();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    if ( age === 0 ) {
        m = 12 + m;
        if (d < 0 || (d === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            m--;
        }
    }

    return age ? age + 'г' : m + 'м';
}

let birthDate = new Date("2020.4.11");
getAge(birthDate);
```

Или для ТС:

```
let d = date.split('.');
let date = d[2]+'.'+d[1]+'.'+d[0];
let birthDate = new Date(date);
getAge(birthDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Кривой способ .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myThisAge() {
     let now = new Date(),
          birthdate = new Date("1978-10-19"),
          diff = now.getTime() - birthdate.getTime(),
          years = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)),
          months = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365.25 / 12))),
          days = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365.24 / 12))) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
          hours = now.getHours(),
          minutes = now.getMinutes(),
          seconds = now.getSeconds();

     out.innerHTML = `<div id="my_age">Претус Игорь<br>
          ${years} года |
          ${months} месяцев | 
          ${days} дней | ${hours} часов | 
          ${minutes} минут | ${seconds} секунд</div>`
}

setInterval(myThisAge, 1000)
```

```css
#out {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:navy;
    border: 5px groove crimson;
    width: 80%;
    color: crimson;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    animation: myLife 5s linear infinite;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.my_age {
    text-align: center; 
}
@keyframes myLife {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 100px navy;
        background-color: red;
    }
    50%{
        box-shadow: inset 500px 500px 105px navy;
        background-color: black;
    
    }
    100%{
        box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 100px navy;

    }
}

.myLife {
    animation: sesons 3s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my_age"><strong>Мой возраст</strong></h1>
    <div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Этот код точно покажет сколько Вам с учётом високосных лет, а так-же месяцев, дней, часов, минут, секунд на момент просмотра. Тут укажите вашу дату рождения  birthdate = new Date("1978-10-19"), Каждую секунду дата обновляется ))))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
  //TODO: довабь какую то дату
  const born = '05.01.1994';
  const ymdArr = born.split('.').map(Number).reverse();
  //с 0а идут месяца по этому откатываем на 1
  ymdArr[1]--;
  const bornDate = new Date(...ymdArr);

  const now = new Date();

  const leapYears = (now.getFullYear() - ymdArr[0]) / 4;

  now.setDate(now.getDate() - Math.floor(leapYears));

  const nowAsTimestamp = now.getTime();
  const bornDateAsTimestamp = bornDate.getTime();

  const ageAsTimestamp = nowAsTimestamp - bornDateAsTimestamp;

  //взял с браузера
  const oneYearInMs = 3.17098e-11;

  const age = Math.floor(ageAsTimestamp * oneYearInMs);
  console.log(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Игорь Претус, спасибо Вам за ответ!
Столкнулся с задачей выводить полное количество лет, месяцев и дней исходя из даты рождения человека. Немного унифицировал Вашу ф-ю. Спасибо еще раз!

```
const myAge = (date: string): { y: number; m: number; d: number } => {
  const now = new Date(),
    birthDate = new Date(date),
    diff = now.getTime() - birthDate.getTime(),
    y = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)),
    m = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365.25 / 12))),
    d = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365.24 / 12))) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return { y, m, d };
};
```

Таким образом при вызове ф-ии ей нужно передать дату в формате строки (например, "yyyy-mm-dd")

```
let bDate: string = bYear + "-" + bMonth + "-" + bDay
```

И, соответственно уже подставлять полученные значения куда следует.

```
const { y, m, d } = myAge(bDate);
```